# Show by using the CLT the following approximation

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

I have the following question

> Suppose $X_1, .. X_n$ are i.i.d with $\mu = 12/5$ and $\sigma = 28/45$. Show using the CLT an approximation to $P(a < \sum_{i=1}^nX_i < b)$ for large $n$ and constants $a,b.$

My work: Because the data is i.i.d then $X = X_1 .. X_n \sim N(12/5, (28/45)^2),$ the CLT is given as the following:  $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.$ Therefore, we must find $$a<\frac{X-(12/5)}{(28/45)/\sqrt{n}}<b.$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here, any suggestions?

Comment: You are likely being downvoted because the "my work" section doesn't really make sense, and reflects a likely misunderstanding somewhere on your part. I have gone ahead and provided an answer, but please do ask questions if you didn't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, the CLT says that as $n$ grows large ($n \to \infty$),
$$
\sqrt{n} \Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu\Big) \to N(0, \sigma^2),
$$
"in distribution." Roughly speaking, you can interpret this statement as for $n$ large enough, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \approx N(\mu, \sigma^2/n).
$$

Returning to your problem, you want to compute
\begin{align*}
P(a < \sum_i X_i < b) &= P(a/n < \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i < b/n) \\ 
&\approx P(a/n < N(\mu, \sigma^2/n) < b/n) \\ 
&= P(\sqrt{n}/\sigma (a/n - \mu) < N(0, 1) < \sqrt{n}/\sigma (b/n - \mu))\\
&= \Phi(\sqrt{n}/\sigma (b/n - \mu)) - \Phi(\sqrt{n}/\sigma (a/n - \mu)), 
\end{align*}
where $\Phi(t) = P(N(0, 1) \leq t)$ is the CDF of a standard Normal random variable.